# Boot-ed Windows Installation doesnt proceed after failure (temporary lock)?

Tags: windows, boot, usb, installation

When I try to boot install windows (clean installation) using USB (probably same could happen with CD, but cant confirm) , and instead of "Clean Install" I choose other option (i.e. "Repair", there are cases, when "Repair" fails and error message comes ( like "windows couldnt be repaired" or something like that). However, If i want to clean install it instead of repairing, after I re-boot with the same USB, it doesnt start from first step (where I could choose CLEAN INSTALL or REPAIR), instead the same last error message is shown directly...

I think there is created something cache in USB storage (or somewhere), which doesnt allow installer to load from ground. How can I avoid that and how can i load the Windows Installer again like I do first time?

Comment: "However, If i want to clean install it instead of repairing, after I re-boot with the same USB, it doesnt start from first step (where I could choose CLEAN INSTALL or REPAIR), instead the same last error message is shown directly..." Using a Windows 10 install disk,to delete existing partitions and reinstall Windows, typical is the simplest way to do what you want.

Comment: "I think there is created something cache in USB storage (or somewhere), which doesnt allow installer to load from ground." - No, this has not happened.